# What's the most efficient way to load feature attributes into a numpy array?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, numpy

I am currently working on an add-on that relies on the user choosing fields of tables (that can be from shapefiles, csv or dbf) that are open in QGIS and then making computations with such data.

Right now I am looping through all the features and collecting the data using the standard cookbook techniques to loop through features and to read attributes, but it is taking too long.  Some tables have about 25,000,000 features, and the actual data loading takes much longer than the computing. Is there any shortcut?  Can I load whole vectors at once or some other similar thing?

It occurs to me that I can just get the file information and go directly to the database in disk and load it from there, but I REALLY want to avoid it.

It seems that the question was not very clear, so here goes what I have now.

```
all_matrix=[]
for f in matrix.getFeatures():
    a=feat.attributes()[origin]
    b=feat.attributes()[destination]
    c=feat.attributes()[flow]
    all_matrix.append([a,b,c])
 matrix=np.array(all_matrix)
```

Comment: use ogr library or shapely library which integrate numpy functions

Comment: What format is your data in? Shapefile? Postgres?

Comment: Any data format that QGIS would accept, probably it would be csv or dbf most of the times.

Answer (score 3):

What about the [QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-a-subset-of-features) flag?

```
all_matrix=[]
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
for feat in matrix.getFeatures(request):
    a=feat.attributes()[origin]
    b=feat.attributes()[destination]
    c=feat.attributes()[flow]
    all_matrix.append([a,b,c])
 matrix=np.array(all_matrix)
```

Comment: OK I just saw how old this is... meh.

Comment: You may get even better performance by generating the matrix in the layout the fields are received. `all_matrix=[f.attributes() for f in l.getFeatures(request)]`. If not all attributes are required, you can further reduce network overhead by using `QgsFeatureRequest.setSubsetOfAttributes`

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the selected features with

```
vl = iface.acitveLayer()
selectedFeatures = vl.selectedFeatures()
```

In case you have many features, may be you can use [selectedFeaturesIds()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a33968fa939503a9e3873c88e5f0ea439) and then query and iterate over these to avoid copying all the features into the memory.

Comment: Anand, this is what I am doing, and it is extremely slow. Please see the update in the question.